# Wrong number of method arguments in class

Tags: visual-studio, class, methods, arguments

I have written a method with 8 arguments in a class. But when call it, I see wrong number of arguments that I have set before that.
I removed the class file. But other called methods are still work.
It seems the methods moved in a place where I don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe on temp folder, remove all items in it:

C:\Users\hassan\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: does it on one classlibrary or that class is on another classlibrary? and if on another classlibrary, do you use nuget packages?

Comment: No. I call the method in a page. I didn't use nuget.